# Point subdomain to root of main site on cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I need to point a subdomain (sub.example.com) to the same root as the main site (example.com). So when someone accesses sub.example.com, the same homepage is displayed.

I tried creating the subdomain and pointing it to /public_html instead of /public_html/sub, but if I access sub.example.com I get redirected to sub.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi, but if I access sub.example.com/index.php I get the right homepage.

My question is, how to properly point a subdomain to the root of the main site on cPanel?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cPanel redirect to "cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi" when there is not index page present in document root. But as you said sub.example.com/index.php  is working so I am not. Add the below lines in .htaccess in public_html folder and give it a try again. Create the .htaccess file if it's not present

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to put a redirect for the subdomain with the domains homepage url

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ReDirects